# Calculate shares of a secret (LSS) in GO

Tags: go, cryptography

Python has the charm-crypto framework where it is implemented the [secretutil](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/toolbox/secretutil.html) class.
By using this class, we can divide a secret into parts. Then we can use all the other functions defined in this class to reconstruct our secret.

For example:

Given a string policy `P` (e.g. *CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 or CONDITION3*), we can use the createPolicy method, in order to parse the string and create a policy object:

`policy_object = createPolicy(CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 or CONDITION3) => ((CONDITION1 and CONDITION2) or CONDITION3)`

Then we can create shares of a secret by utilizing the calculateSharesList method, like:

`sharesOfASecret = calculateSharesList(someSecret, policy_object)`

Last but not least, we can use the `prune` method which `determines whether a given set of attributes satisfies the policy` and the `getCoefficients` method that calculates the different coefficients of the attributes over a given policy string.

So, does any LSS plugin exist for GO? Or are there any ideas on how to implement the above in GO?

In short, what I need to achieve is:

1. Give a function some policy as a string
2. The function constructs a policy object (charm-crypto: `createPolicy()`)
3. The policy object is then used to calculate shares of a secret (charm-crypto: `calculateSharesList()`)

Then for decryption:

4. Another function takes as an input some attributes and a policy
5. The function checks if the attributes satisfy the policy (charm-crypto: `prune()`)
6. Calculate the coefficients of the policy (charm-crypto: `getCoefficients()`)
7. Reconstruct the secret

Answer (score 0):

George, I think what you've come across is the idea of **Threshold Secret Sharing** which happens to be behind what you mentioned in great detail. In order to achieve this in any language, I'd recommend you to go through Berry Shoenmakers which is a detailed, advanced and comprehensive version of Secret Sharing:

> [A Simple Publicly Verifiable Secret Sharing Scheme and its Application to Electronic Voting](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eberry/papers/crypto99.pdf)

However, a starting point for what you're trying to achieve can be:

> [Various Implementations of Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme](https://github.com/SSSaaS)

There's also a Go implementation of the scheme that you can go through before getting your hands on your task.

> Cavaet: **Be careful, how you generate your secrets and tweak around. :D**